# Dynamic grid in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math, ecmascript-6

I have a Grid that I built but its not working exactly correct. Looks like may Math my be a little off.

So my input data is just a pseudocode array below. But just know that its made up of multiple React components and those objects have a property called span which changes based on the object itself.

**pseudocode data input**

```
array = [
  {child.. span=100}, {child..span=50}, {child.. span=50}, {child.. span=100}, {child..span=100}
];
```

I want to create a multi dimensional array with the output matching the input span values. By that I mean if span is 100 then it should create a row with a column inside it. If the next childs span prop value is 50 then it should create a new row and add that child to it. If the following is another 50 it should **not create** a new row **but instead** just add that new child to a second span in the **last row** and so on...

So basically all 100 spans should be in their own row and span. Any 50 span should be in their own row together in separate spans.

```
Example pseudocode structure:  [ [ {col} ], [ {col}, {col} ], [ {col} ] ]
```

outer array represents grid, inner brackets are rows and inside those are cols. This structure changes based on the span size as I said above. the grid for now is 2 x 2 but that could change.

**Grid code**

```
  const grid = [];
  const size = 2;
  array.forEach((child, index) => {
    const spanPercent = child.props.span;
    const size = 100 / spanPercent;
    const rowIndex = Math.floor(index / size);
    const colIndex = index % size;
    const row = grid[rowIndex] || (grid[rowIndex] = []);
    row[colIndex] = child;
  });
```

The above is giving me an incorrect
output based on the span sizes in my pseudocode code.

**output**

```
 [ [ {col}, {col} ], [ {col} ], [ {col} ]
```

This is incorrect as the input is. **100 | 50 | 50 | 100 | 100**
Based on the input my output should be

```
[ [ {col} ], [ {col}, {col} ], [ {col} ]
```

Anyone out there can help correct my math. Or maybe a better way to write this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it easier by using the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method to keep track of the cumulative `span` of the current row you're appending each `child` to in `grid`:

```js
const array = [{ props: { span: 100 } }, { props: { span: 50 } }, { props: { span: 50 } }, { props: { span: 100 } }, { props: { span: 100 } }];
const grid = []
const maxSpan = 100

array.reduce((acc, child) => {
  const { span } = child.props
  const total = acc + span

  if (total > maxSpan) {
    grid.push([child])
    return span
  } else {
    grid[grid.length - 1].push(child)
    return total
  }
}, 100); // force reduce() to start a new row with first child

console.log(JSON.stringify(grid));
```

Your mistake was related to using the `index` parameter of [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), since that index does not directly correlate to the `rowIndex` and `colIndex` in your jagged 2D array. Not every row has `size` columns in your `grid`.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Patrick but your code creates an output of [ [ {col} ], [ {col} ], [ {col} ] which is a row for each one which is unfortunately not what I'm after.

Comment: Oops missing a bracket but hopefully you get the idea that the code is not outputting correctly. [ [ {col} ], [ {col} ], [ {col} ] ]. It should not create a new row every time for spans that are set at 50. Those should be grouped into their own row. row with 50|50.  The 100 spans get their own row.

Comment: @me-me maybe your code is not the same as mine. I just edited it to add example data analogous to yours, and it prints exactly as you wanted.

Comment: Weird I'm going to try break down my code and see why its failing.